# Enviar pela função mail do php dados provindos de uma tabela

Tags: php, mysql, envio-de-email

Olá Dev´s estou há uns três dias tentando elaborar uma forma de enviar dados de uma tabela pela função [mail](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php) do php. Enviar dados de apenas uma coluna é basicamente fácil, mas fica complicado quando desejo enviar dados de mais de uma coluna. 
Isso porque eu preciso fazer um `while` para chamar todos os dados, mas como farei para enviar esses dados chamados no corpo do email da função `mail`? 
No exemplo abaixo reparem que o quarto argumento da função email é justamente a variável que contém um conjunto de outras variáveis.

Porem quando o email é submetido apenas o último elemento da variável `$html` é mandado.

```
$buscando = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guardapedidos WHERE id_cliente = '$idDoCliente'")
or die(mysql_error());
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array( $buscando )) {


  $nomeProdutoG = $linha['nomeProdutoG'];
  $quantidadeG = $linha['quantidadeProdutoG'];
  $precoProdutoG = $linha['precoProdutoG'];
  $subTotalG = $linha['subTotalG'];
  $totalG = $linha['totalG'];


  echo  $html = "
     <b>Nome</b> $nomeProdutoG.<br>
     <b>Quantidade</b> $quantidadeG.<br>
     <b>Preço</b> $precoProdutoG.<br>
     <hr>
   ";

}

$envio = mail($destino, $assunto, $html, $headers);
```

Comment: Estude sobre [Operadores de String](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.string.php), vai lhe ajudar no seu atual problema e em futuros projetos.

Comment: Valdiney França, estou com um problema para enviar email com essa função, você poderia me dizer como configurou seu smtp? Valeu.

Answer (score 2):

O que está acontecendo é que você esta criando novamente a variável `$hmtl` cada iteração do *loop*, você precisa concatenar os registros, tente assim.

```
$buscando = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guardapedidos WHERE id_cliente = '$idDoCliente'")
or die(mysql_error());
$html = ''; // cria variável $html fora do loop
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array( $buscando )) {


  $nomeProdutoG = $linha['nomeProdutoG'];
  $quantidadeG = $linha['quantidadeProdutoG'];
  $precoProdutoG = $linha['precoProdutoG'];
  $subTotalG = $linha['subTotalG'];
  $totalG = $linha['totalG'];

  // concatena a cada iteração
  $html .= " 
     <b>Nome</b> $nomeProdutoG.<br />
     <b>Quantidade</b> $quantidadeG.<br />
     <b>Preço</b> $precoProdutoG.<br />
     <hr />
   ";

}

$envio = mail($destino, $assunto, $html, $headers);
```